# What is php composer and what does dependency manager mean?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm trying to understand what exactly composer is and does. I'm totally new to it and what the concepts are that surround it.

The things I have problems with are:

- What is a dependency? What does it mean in PHP?
- What does it mean that composer is a dependency manager?
- What is the main argument for using composer or a dependency manager in general?

Comment: Define *"I've been stuck"* - What exactly is the issue and how has the [official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) been unclear?

Comment: I couldn't get the idea behind it , should I use it if am using cURL ?

Comment: What does *curl* (a command-line application) have to do with either PHP or Composer?

Comment: I don't know am really confused now now curl is used to download file from GitHub right I saw a tutorial on YouTube where they use composer to download files also please tell me the difference between both I have been searching a lot and can't understand the both thing ?

Comment: I repeat: [The official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management) explains exactly what Composer is. Excerpt: *Composer:

 -  Enables you to declare the libraries you depend on.
 - Finds out which versions of which packages can and need to be installed, and installs them (meaning it downloads them into your project).*

Comment: And just because the two programs happen to both be able to download files does not mean their intended usage is anywhere close to the same. *curl* is a "simple" command-line application, Composer is a tool for managing dependencies for PHP projects.

Answer (score 11):

> can you please explain the main reason why I should use composer and
>   what is a dependency

You use it to install *libraries* made by other people.

Example: you're dealing with dates in your PHP application. You can use `date` function and `DateTime` class that comes with PHP. However, you need to display a human-readable date in format of "5 minutes ago" or "in 2 hours" etc.

So you get to developing and you realize that you're going to spend time on this feature. It's a nice to have, but it takes time to do it.

A wise developer will think "*Someone definitely had the same issue as I did, let's see how they solved it*" and you stumble upon this library: [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Now you want to use this library because it takes care of your problem. Your option is to download it from github and add to your project manually, which means placing it in some directory, including it in your app etc.

OR you can use Composer and you can tell Composer that you want a specific *version* of the library. In your terminal, you type:

`composer require "nesbot/carbon: ~1.21"`

Composer downloads the specific version of the library, places it in `vendor/` directory and provides you with an autoloader.

For you, that means you can:

- Install libraries made by other developers
- Track which version of libraries you installed and lock down your project to that specific library version
- You get an autoloader, so it's simple for you to add libraries to your project, you don't have to manually type `require` or `include` because all you need to do is `include vendor/autoload.php` to gain access to all libraries installed via composer.

Since you most likely had issues with dates, databases, mailing and so on - other people had them as well and some of those people were awesome enough to create free code for the rest of us to use. Composer helps you get that code and manage it.